# How to get `model` property in `route` path?

Tags: ember.js, ember-model

How can I get the current `route` model within current routes action method?
I am keep getting error. any one help me here?

my route:

import Ember from 'ember';

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {

    if(this.store.hasRecordForId('card-list', params.id)){
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            model: this.store.peekRecord('card-list', params.id )
        })
    }
  },
  actions:{
    formValidateBeforeNext:function(){
        this.modelFor(this.routeName).get("id");//not works
        console.log(this.controller.get('model').get("id"));//not works
        console.log(this.get('model').get("id"))//not works
        return;
        // this.transitionTo('cs2i.balance.balanceReview');
    }
  }
});
```

getting error as : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of null`

Answer (score 0):

To get the model within a route action, you can use

```
this.controller.get("model.id")
```

Comment: I tried both of this: not working
`console.log("route name", this.modelFor(this.routeName).get("model.id") );
    console.log("route name", this.controller.get("model.id") );`

Answer (score 0):

finally I tried like: 
`this.controllerFor(this.routeName).get('model')` -it works for me.
Very thanks to all!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.currentModel` to access the model in the action methods.